# How to make a commutative square in tikzcd with explicit functions

Tags: tikz-cd

I have a square I'm trying to show commutes. Both compositions give an output that could a priori be different. How do I get them in one diagram like this

[image]

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misinterpret the question. You seem to be aware of `tikz-cd` since you tagged the question with it, so you may just use it to get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
 f \arrow[r,mapsto]\arrow[d,mapsto] & \bar f\arrow[d,mapsto]\\
 G(q)\circ f \arrow[r,mapsto]& \displaystyle\frac{q\circ\bar f}{G(f)\circ f}\\
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, that works exactly. It didn't cross my mind that it looks exactly like a fraction. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the image of the user @Schrödinger's cat, I have used the `xy` (or `xy-pic`) package with the option `all` that reproduce the same tips for the arrows (the same image) of your initial image. Here there is the link for the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xypic).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=2pc@C=2.5pc{
f \ar@{|->}[d] \ar@{|->}[r] & \bar{f} \ar@{|->}[d] \\
G(q)\circ f \ar@{|->}[r] & \dfrac{q\circ\bar{f}}{G(f)\circ f,}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]